# How to display the added data in the table on clicking add button using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add data to table on clicking add button. but in doing so, it doesnt show the added data that is data1 in the table:

```
import "moment/locale/pt-br";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      code: "23",
      coordinates: "45",
      number: "1",
      status: "New"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      code: "24",
      coordinates: "46",
      number: "2",
      status: "Approved"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      code: "25",
      coordinates: "47",
      number: "3",
      status: "Failed"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      code: "26",
      coordinates: "48",
      number: "4",
      status: "Finished"
    }
  ];
  const handleAdd = () => {
    const data1 = {
      id: "5",
      code: "27",
      coordinates: "49",
      number: "5",
      status: "Finished"
    };
    data.push(data1);
  };
  return (
    <div classname="wrapper">
      <div className="title"> Title </div>
      <div className="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
        {" "}
        Add{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="list_details">
        <div className="table">
          <div className="table_header">
            <div className="table_row">
              <div className="table_cell">First</div>
              <div className="table_cell">second</div>
              <div className="table_cell">third</div>
              <div className="table_cell">fourth</div>
              <div className="table_cell">fifth</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="table_body">
            {data.map((d) => {
              return (
                <div className="table_row" key={d.id}>
                  <div className="table_cell">{d.id}</div>
                  <div className="table_cell">{d.code}</div>
                  <div className="table_cell">{d.coordinates}</div>
                  <div className="table_cell">{d.number}</div>
                  <div className="table_cell">{d.status}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

you can find code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dates-forked-skrj2?file=/src/index.js

also i am new to work on any backend. could someone help me figure out how to add a rest api (create operation) there.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
i have tried using state like so

```
const [shownData, setShownData] = React.useState(data);
const handleAdd = () => {
    data.push(data1);
    setShownData(data);
}
```

but this still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you make a small example and copy the code into the question so we don't need to go off-site to see what's wrong?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review any of the documentation about [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) or [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I'd recommend doing that first because it will be key in solving your issue and understand the basic functionality of react.

Comment: Some hints from looking at your code: Use semantic html, eg don't use a `div` as a `button` and I'd suggest looking into using a `table` instead of div soup :) You also got `classname` all lowercase in your first `div` and `{" "}` is something you can and should do with css.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky: i have edited my question with state usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit for the purpose of this question and added some semantic html.

Below should work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {
            id: "1",
            code: "23",
            coordinates: "45",
            number: "1",
            status: "New"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            code: "24",
            coordinates: "46",
            number: "2",
            status: "Approved"
        },
    ]);

    const handleAdd = () => {
        const data1 = {
            id: "5",
            code: "27",
            coordinates: "49",
            number: "5",
            status: "Finished"
        };
        setData([...data, data1]);
    };

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="title"> Title </div>
            <button type="button" className="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
                Add
            </button>

            <div className="list_details">
                <table className="table">
                    <thead className="table_header">
                        <tr className="table_row">
                            <th className="table_cell">First</th>
                            <th className="table_cell">second</th>
                            <th className="table_cell">third</th>
                            <th className="table_cell">fourth</th>
                            <th className="table_cell">fifth</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="table_body">
                        {data.map((d) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="table_row" key={d.id}>
                                    <td className="table_cell">{d.id}</td>
                                    <td className="table_cell">{d.code}</td>
                                    <td className="table_cell">{d.coordinates}</td>
                                    <td className="table_cell">{d.number}</td>
                                    <td className="table_cell">{d.status}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

PS your code didn't have any typescript so I kept it to Javascript